# Any concrete example of ''right identity and left inverse do not imply a group''?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

In the abstract algebra class, we have proved the fact that right identity and right inverse imply a group, while right identity and left inverse do not.

My question:
Are there any good examples of sets (with operations on) with right identity and left inverse, not being a group?

> To be specific, suppose $(X,\cdot)$ is a set with a binary operation satisfies the following conditions:
>
> (i) $(a\cdot b)\cdot c=a\cdot (b\cdot c)$ for any $a,b,c\in X$;
>
> (ii) There exists $e\in X$ such that for every $a\in X$, $a\cdot e=a$;
>
> (iii) For any $a\in X$, there exists $b\in X$ such that $b\cdot a=e$.
>
> I want an example of $(X,\cdot)$ which is not a group.

Comment: @ZhenLin: I think rhenskyyy means that she know that right identity and left inverse cannot ensure the conditions being a group, but I think she want a concrete example to show that there exists a non-group set with multiplication satisfying associative law, right identity and left inverse.

Comment: @jerrysciencemath You don't need to put your name in the post if you edit it.  I think your edit is good, so leave it all, but take out "Edit(by jerrysciencemath):"

Comment: See also: [Is a semigroup G with left identity and right inverses a group?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433546/is-a-semigroup-g-with-left-identity-and-right-inverses-a-group)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\matrix{a&a&a\cr b&b&b\cr c&c&c\cr}$$ That is, $xy=x$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: This is a nifty and easy to remember example!

Comment: You didn't tell which one is $e$, so I have difficulty finding the left inverse of (say) $b$. I know any one will do, but I think you need to be specific.

Comment: OP didn't posit a *unique* left inverse, and I don't see why I need to be specific. Isn't it enough that, as you point out, any one will do?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Is there any example satisfying unique left inverse and unique right identity besides the conditions in the problem?

Comment: @jerry, I don't know.