# Proving $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$ in a set with only a one-sided identity and one-sided inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G$ is a set which is closed under mutiplication, associative, and every element has a right identity and right inverse. 
I have to prove that $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$.

Is proving this at all possibe without assuming $a^{-1}$ has a two sided inverse?

The proof I thought of was $a^{-1}*(a^{-1})^{-1}=(a^{-1})^{-1}*a^{-1}=e=a^{-1}*a=a*a^{-1}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is multiplication commutative? Otherwise your proof is wrong (or needs more intermediate steps).

Comment: How do you know they commute? You just know that $a * a' = e$ and $a' * (a')' = e$ (where $x'$ is inverse). It would work if the binary operation was commutative, but in that case all one-sided things are actually both-sided.

Comment: My proof has assumed that inverses commute. I know my proof is wrong, as I have made an unjustified assumption. I am looking for a proof under the conditions stated in the problem.

Comment: I can only come up with one if at least $e$ is in the center of $G$ (i.e. $e$ is a two-sided identity)...

Comment: See also the related (but different) question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433546/is-a-semigroup-g-with-left-identity-and-right-inverses-a-group

Answer (score 4):

In your question a right identity must be common for all elements. Then a solution is as follows:

Let $x$ is a right inverse for $a^{-1}$. Then $a^{-1}a=a^{-1}ae=a^{-1}aa^{-1}x=a^{-1}ex=a^{-1}x=e$, so $a^{-1}$ is a left inverse for $a$.