# Is a semigroup with unique right identity and left inverse a group?

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

We know that a semigroup with a right identity and right inverse for all elements is a group (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65239/right-identity-and-right-inverse-implies-a-group)). Symmetrically, also a left identity together with a left inverse implies a group.
We also know that a semigroup with a right identity and a left inverse is NOT necessarily a group (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433546/is-a-semigroup-g-with-left-identity-and-right-inverses-a-group)).
My questions are:

1. in a semigroup, is the existence of a UNIQUE right identity together with the existence of a left inverse enough to have a group?
2. in a semigroup, is the existence of a right identity together with the existence of a UNIQUE left inverse enough to have a group?

I think both these claims are false,  ut haven't found a counter-example so far.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27720/do-these-conditions-on-a-semigroup-define-a-group

Comment: The standard example in your link shows that (2) does not hold. Let $X$ be a set with more than one element, $e\in X$ one of them. Define $ab=a$ for all $a,b\in X$. Then $ae=a$ for all $a$, so $e$ is a right identity. And for any $a\in A$, the unique inverse of $a$ in $A$ relative to $e$ is $e$, for $xa=e$ if and only if $x=e$. But this is not a group.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It's not clear to me what "left inverse" means if the right identity is not unique. Is this a standard notion? If we interpret "$x$ is a left inverse of $a$" to mean "$xa$ is a right identity", then "every element has a unique left inverse" does imply "there is unique right identity".

Comment: @bof: it would mean a left inverse relative to a given identity; if there are multiple identities, then you would need to have an inverse relative to each of them, which that example does have. Note that you are replying to a comment that is well over a year old.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has been shown in a comment, (2) does not hold.  However, (1) does.

Let $e$ be the unique right identity, and for any $x$, let $x'$ denote a left inverse.

For any $x$,
$$
e = x''x' = x''ex' = x''x'xx' = ex x'.
$$
Hence, for any $y$,
$$
y = ye = yexx' = y xx',
$$
which shows that $xx'$ is a right identity.  Since it is unique, $xx' = e$.  Hence every element $x$ has a two-sided inverse.

Finally, for any $x$,
$$
ex = xx'x = xe = x,
$$
so $e$ is a two-sided identity and the semigroup is a group.