# One-sided monoids and groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semigroups, finite-semigroups

It is known that a semigroup with left identity element and left invertibility is a group.

I noticed that I can make an unnamed group-like structure with some tweaks. I call a semigroup $\langle G,*\rangle$ a **demimonoid** iff:

- There exists a **unique** right identity element.

Furthermore, I call a demimonoid a **demigroup** iff:

- For every element in $G$, there exists a **unique** left inverse.

The key motivation is from that the "one-sided definition" of groups derive that the left identity is also the right identity by using left invertibility.

Note that uniqueness matters. A notable non-example of a demimonoid is the left zero semigroup:

$$
\begin{array}{l|ll}
* & x & y \\ \hline
x & x & x \\
y & y & y
\end{array}
$$

Every two-element demimonoid is a group. An example of a three-element demimonoid which is not a monoid (nor a demigroup) is:

$$
\begin{array}{l|ll}
* & x & y & z \\ \hline
x & x & x & x \\
y & y & y & y \\
z & x & x & z
\end{array}
$$
where $z$ is the unique right identity element.

I see no example of a demigroup that is not a group. All three-element demigroup is a group, namely, the cyclic group. Is every demigroup a group? If not, what is the smallest demigroup which is not a group?

Comment: Have you seen [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163347/is-a-semigroup-with-unique-right-identity-and-left-inverse-a-group). ?  It proves that a unique right indentity together with possibly non-unique left inverses implies that it is a group. Since I have a gold-badge, if I mark the question as a duplicate it will automatically close, so I want to give you an opportunity to check if it does answer your question before doing it.

Comment: @ArturiMagidin Yeah, it does answer my question. Sorry for dupe!