# Proving right identity and left inverse implies group

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

Given G is a set with associative binary opeartion.

Given for any,$a,b \in G$ , there exists $a'$ in G such that $ be=b, $. And $a'a=e$ First i try to show that $eb=b$.

Given,

$be=b$

$beb=bb$

$b'beb=b'bb$

$b'beb=eb=b$

$b'beb=b$

$eb=b$

Now for any element c of set G i want to show that $ce=c$

$ce=cc'e=ec=c$

To show right inverse :

Given $a'a=e$,
$a'aa'=ea'$
$a'eaa'=ea'$

$a'aa'=a'$

$a'aa'=a'e$

$aa'=e$ (i believe cancellation laws can be proved by using left inverse, so using them)

Is this correct ? Thank you

Comment: You assumed $eb=b$ to prove $eb=b.$ (When writing "$b'beb=eb=b$")

Comment: @AnneBauvalno. started with $be=b$

Comment: Your equalities $ce=cc'e=ec$ are wrong. And the sentence just before is strange (We have $ce=c$ by hypothesis, for every element $c$ in $G$, so you do not have to show it). Anyway, please look at the proposed duplicate. The answer gives a counterexample to what you wanted to prove (up to exchanging right and left, which is easy).

Comment: @AnneBauval I have edited question. its different question now

Comment: its unique right identity element instead

Comment: You should not change a question when you already received comments and link to a duplicate. Better post your new question in a new post. Anyway your new question would also be a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163347/is-a-semigroup-with-unique-right-identity-and-left-inverse-a-group I rolled back to keep the body consistent with the title and the closure box. @KurtG.

Comment: As for your proof attempt: even with the stronger hypothesis of uniqueness of the right identity (which you don't use), you still have the flaw  indicated in my 1st comment, and the oddities of the 2nd one.

Comment: @AnneBauval i am not sure what exactly is meaning of uniqueness of right identity..can you help ?

Comment: Didn't [the answer there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3163547/386889) suffice? (uniqueness of right identity is used explicitely there)