# Examples of semigroups with a subgroup and more than one left identity and some other properties

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

We are looking for some (*finite and infinite*) examples of **non-monoid semigroups** $S$ **containing a non-trivial subgroup** $H$ satisfying the following conditions:

**(1)** $S$ has more than one left identity;

**(2)** $1_H$ is a left identity of $S$;

**(3)** There are some $h\in H$ such that $sh=1_H$ for some $s\neq h^{-1}$ (in $S$), where $ h^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $h$ in $H$.

**Note.** Such examples were not found among the semigroups of functions, matrices, and similar to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the semigroup $(S,\circ)$ where $S=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and
$x\circ y=|x|y$. It is obvious that $H=(0,+\infty)$ is a subgroup of $S$. Now

(1) $S$ contains the left identities $\pm 1$, and no right identity.

(2) $1_H=1$ is a left identity of $S$.

(3) Putting **$s=\frac{-1}{h}$**, for every $h\in H$, we have $s\circ h=1_H$ and $s\neq h^{-1}$.

Also, see [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433546/is-a-semigroup-g-with-left-identity-and-right-inverses-a-group#:~:text=Semigroup%20with%20left%20unit%20](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433546/is-a-semigroup-g-with-left-identity-and-right-inverses-a-group#:%7E:text=Semigroup%20with%20left%20unit%20)